# Keep § when pasting from word

Tags: tinymce

I'm trying to paste content from a word doc into a tinymce instance. The content contains the § (paragraph) character, but TinyMce changes it into an li tag.

Is there a way to config TinyMce to allow special characters like §?

Comment: Does it work with the current demo on https://www.tinymce.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is behavior around the `Paste` plugin when a sentence starts with that character.

When it starts with that character the `Paste` plugin treats that like a list element.  If the character is anywhere other than the first character TinyMCE does not create a list element.

The best thing to do is to open a bug report on the issue tracker for TinyMCE so the developers are aware of this issue.

https://github.com/tinymce/tinymce/issues